# Razor syntax inside resx file

Tags: c#, razor, resx

I have the following razor syntax inside the view:

```
(@Html.ActionLink(SQPStrings.ForgotPassword, "ResetPassword", "User", new { Area = "Authentication" }, new { }))
```

In the resx file I have the following text:

> Password: use your password (case sensitive) (insert the actionlink here)

I cannot seem to find how to proceed with this, can someone help me get in the right direction? I know I need to do a `String.Format` in the view and add the parameters but not excactly how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define placeholders for `string.Format` in the string value of the resx file:

`Password: use your password (case sensitive) ({0})`

and then format the value into the translated string in the Razor view. 
Render the resulting string with `Html.Raw` or the `<a href=".."\>` contained in it will be escaped.

```
var actionLink = Html.ActionLink("Link name" , "ResetPassword", "User", new { Area = "Authentication" }, new { }));
var resetDisplay = string.Format(SQPStrings.ForgotPassword, actionLink);
@Html.Raw(resetDisplay)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your text in .resx file by replacing "insert the actionlink here" part with placeholder {0} like this:

```
<data name="ForgotPassword" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Password: use your password (case sensitive) ({0})</value>
</data>
```

In the view you should use `string.Format()` in combination with `Html.Row()` helper like this:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(SQPStrings.ForgotPassword, Html.ActionLink(link, "ResetPassword", "User", new { Area = "Authentication" }, new { }))))
```

where `link` is the string name to your link.

Comment: This works great, thank you. I was assuming that one needed to put everything in placeholders but that didn't work.